# How to create a discussion post when a custom post is created?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, comments

I have a custom post type 'report' that is just a title and some content. I want to know if it's possible that when I create a 'report' it creates a discussion post where you'd leave feedback about the 'report'. I'm new to Wordpress dev, and haven't found much info on create two simultaneous post.

I kinda want to do it myself for the learning experience, but if there's a plugin that'd also be cool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible `publish_report` action triggered whenever a report is published, or if it is edited and the status is changed to publish.
You have to done some error hadling.

```
function create_discussion_post( $ID, $post ) {
    //Write a code to create a discussion post.
}
add_action( 'publish_report', 'create_discussion_post');
```

Comment: Ok so I found the documentation for `publish_'post-type'` after a bit of searching, thanks a lot. However I know it might be a bit noobish, but `create_discussion_post` is that my own custom function or is it something Wordpress? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Nvm, `create_discussion_post` is my own function lol

Comment: Sorry again, what does $ID and $post do in this function? Do they already have a value, or do I give it to them?